# Not getting specific search result on 'query_string' ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, search, query-string, opensearch

The following company details are **indexed in my elastic search**

```
[{
    "_index": "test_company",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "9303000d-b167-4d7c-b233-43a43c4a7e60",
    "_score": 2.4849067,
    "_source": {
        "id": "9303000d-b167-4d7c-b233-43a43c4a7e60",
        "name": "My Property Company",
        "phone": "11484473106",
        "email": "johnie.schinner@hotmail.com",
        "website": "https://www.walmart.com",
        "ein": "731087415",
        "address": "Apt. 837 5371 Carroll Estates, Zboncakbury, LA 53957-3670",
        "zip": "99950",
        "city": "Ketchikan",
        "state": "Alaska",
        "country": "US",
        "fileId": "",
        "status": "Active"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "test_company",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "f302ef6a-f259-4980-ad1e-48de33e34799",
    "_score": 1.8173966,
    "_source": {
        "byPhone": "byPhone",
        "website": "https://www.walmart.com",
        "zip": "99950",
        "status": "Active",
        "ein": "427297769",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-11T04:39:50.717Z",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "address": "056 Robin Island, Arliefurt, MA 28632-8802",
        "byName": "byName",
        "email": "nathanael.marks@hotmail.com",
        "country": "US",
        "name": "Walmart",
        "state": "Alaska",
        "city": "Ketchikan",
        "byCreatedAt": "byCreatedAt",
        "fileId": "9b705ead-df91-424c-bad9-ccf1db477f3c",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-11T05:49:02.759Z",
        "byEmail": "byEmail",
        "id": "f302ef6a-f259-4980-ad1e-48de33e34799",
        "phone": "14844731064"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "test_company",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "270c1a72-0f54-4004-8efc-70fd3adc0b3d",
    "_score": 1.8173966,
    "_source": {
        "id": "270c1a72-0f54-4004-8efc-70fd3adc0b3d",
        "name": "Walmart",
        "phone": "14844731064",
        "email": "nick.hyatt@hotmail.com",
        "website": "https://www.walmart.com",
        "ein": "058107938",
        "address": "0440 Neville Camp, Schinnerbury, AK 30194-5833",
        "zip": "99950",
        "city": "Ketchikan",
        "state": "Alaska",
        "country": "US",
        "fileId": "",
        "status": "Active"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "test_company",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "b695acb2-980a-459d-88d8-e16fc47eead8",
    "_score": 1.5686159,
    "_source": {
        "id": "b695acb2-980a-459d-88d8-e16fc47eead8",
        "name": "My Property Company",
        "phone": "14844731064",
        "email": "kristofer.larkin@hotmail.com",
        "website": "https://www.walmart.com",
        "ein": "040723577",
        "address": "20361 Veum Overpass, Erniechester, ID 19244",
        "zip": "99950",
        "city": "Ketchikan",
        "state": "Alaska",
        "country": "US",
        "fileId": "",
        "status": "Active"
    }
}]
```

I am trying to search the following string `r@hot` on the email field using **query_string**. I am expecting it to return the following data,

```
    [{
    "_index": "test_company",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "9303000d-b167-4d7c-b233-43a43c4a7e60",
    "_score": 2.4849067,
    "_source": {
        "id": "9303000d-b167-4d7c-b233-43a43c4a7e60",
        "name": "My Property Company",
        "phone": "11484473106",
        "email": "johnie.schinner@hotmail.com",
        "website": "https://www.walmart.com",
        "ein": "731087415",
        "address": "Apt. 837 5371 Carroll Estates, Zboncakbury, LA 53957-3670",
        "zip": "99950",
        "city": "Ketchikan",
        "state": "Alaska",
        "country": "US",
        "fileId": "",
        "status": "Active"
    }
}]
```

but it is **returning all of the data above** ...

So far I have tried many combinations two of them are the following,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"query_string": {
          "query": "r@hot*", 
          "fields": ["email"],
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result: It returns all the data

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"query_string": {
          "query": "*r@hot*", 
          "fields": ["email"],
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result: It returns nothing

Is there any other way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add the mapping of the index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

This is a case where you hit your head against the text analyser pipeline.

`email` is a field of type `text`.
On which the default text analyser is applied.

## To understand

you can use the following api call:

```json
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "johnie.schinner@hotmail.com"
}
```

Giving you

```json
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "johnie.schinner",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "hotmail.com",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 27,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Indeed two tokens.

But when you are going to perform your query against the `email` field. Your query is also going to be using the pipeline.

You can notice it if you are to use the `explain` flag in your query.

```json
GET 75680788/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "r@hot*",
            "fields": [
              "email"
            ],
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}
```

You get:

```json
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_shard": "[75680788][0]",
        "_node": "CTqyybxMQGi088cQT29ewA",
        "_index": "75680788",
        "_id": "7hluxYYBSMeA9tKN7RQT",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "b695acb2-980a-459d-88d8-e16fc47eead8",
          "name": "My Property Company",
          "phone": "14844731064",
          "email": "kristofer.larkin@hotmail.com",
          "website": "https://www.walmart.com",
          "ein": "040723577",
          "address": "20361 Veum Overpass, Erniechester, ID 19244",
          "zip": "99950",
          "city": "Ketchikan",
          "state": "Alaska",
          "country": "US",
          "fileId": "",
          "status": "Active"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0,
          "description": "ConstantScore(email:r email:hot*)^0.0",
          "details": []
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[75680788][0]",
        "_node": "CTqyybxMQGi088cQT29ewA",
        "_index": "75680788",
        "_id": "7xluxYYBSMeA9tKN7RQT",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "9303000d-b167-4d7c-b233-43a43c4a7e60",
          "name": "MyPropertyCompany",
          "phone": "11484473106",
          "email": "johnie.schinner@hotmail.com",
          "website": "https://www.walmart.com",
          "ein": "731087415",
          "address": "Apt.8375371CarrollEstates,Zboncakbury,LA53957-3670",
          "zip": "99950",
          "city": "Ketchikan",
          "state": "Alaska",
          "country": "US",
          "fileId": "",
          "status": "Active"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0,
          "description": "ConstantScore(email:r email:hot*)^0.0",
          "details": []
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[75680788][0]",
        "_node": "CTqyybxMQGi088cQT29ewA",
        "_index": "75680788",
        "_id": "8BluxYYBSMeA9tKN7RQT",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "9303000d-b167-4d7c-b233-43a43c4a7e60",
          "name": "MyPropertyCompany",
          "phone": "11484473106",
          "email": "johnie.begood@hotmail.com",
          "website": "https://www.walmart.com",
          "ein": "731087415",
          "address": "Apt.8375371CarrollEstates,Zboncakbury,LA53957-3670",
          "zip": "99950",
          "city": "Ketchikan",
          "state": "Alaska",
          "country": "US",
          "fileId": "",
          "status": "Active"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0,
          "description": "ConstantScore(email:r email:hot*)^0.0",
          "details": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You get 2 queries, `(email:r email:hot*)` and by default the `OR` operator is applied.

## Solution

I suggest you use a type `keyword` and this should work.

```json
GET 75680788/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*r@hot*",
            "fields": [
              "email.keyword"
            ],
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}
```